# c++ File input/output

Tags: c++, pointers, file-io

I am trying to read from a file using fgets and sscanf. In my file, I have characters on each line of the while which I wish to put into a vector. So far, I have the following:

```
FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if(!fp)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
  }
  // Read file
  int line_count = 0;
  char buffer[1024];
  while(fgets(buffer, 1023, fp))
  {
    // Increment line counter
    line_count++;

    char *bufferp = buffer;

    ...

    while(*bufferp != '\n')
    {
      char *tmp;
      if(sscanf(bufferp, "%c", tmp) != 1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error reading axiom on "
                "line %d in file %s\n", line_count, filename);
        return 0;
      }

      axiom.push_back(tmp);
      printf("put %s in axiom vector\n", axiom[axiom.size()-1]);

      // increment buffer pointer
      bufferp++;
    }
  }
```

my axiom vector is defined as `vector<char *> axiom;`. When I run my program, I get a seg fault. It happens when I do the `sscanf`. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp` is a pointer and not an array so reading into it results in a buffer overrun.

for a start you should change the decleration of `tmp` to:

```
  char *tmp = malloc(SOME_MAXIMUM_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

and then you should remember to free all of the pointers in `axioms` when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

A safer approach is to use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>`.

The `string` type handles memory allocation for your text.  See also `getline` and `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: if you're going to take the step of using a std::string (and I wholeheartedly recommend you do), you may also want to switch to the C++ I/O classes for your file I/O (namely, fstream).